# How to improve the startup time of an Android app?

Tags: java, android, apk

What is the recommended best practice for minimizing the startup time of an android application?

Comment: Whats you app about?
If you load much files, maybe you can load them at runtime?
If you do much calculations, maybe you can save the results and reuse them? you should get more specific for a good answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Start by understanding what makes it take so long to start up; then work to minimize that time.

That may sound flippant, but it's not. There's no one magic bullet for improving program performance. Database optimizations, threading, and other techniques may help, but no one could make a sound recommendation without knowing what makes it take a long time in your particular program.

In the case of Android apps, there are tools such as [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html) that can help you determine what your program is doing while it starts up.

Answer (score 5):

Get long-running work off the main application thread, using `AsyncTask` or your own background threads.

Use Traceview to figure out what is taking your time.