# App takes too long to start-up

Tags: android, performance, startup

I have and android app which takes >=5 seconds to show up after it's icon is clicked.

As soon as I click the icon, I get the black screen with name of the app in status bar. After 5+ seconds, the home screen appears.

I referred [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706251/how-to-improve-the-startup-time-of-an-android-app) on SO which and I got following result from stack trace

```
16:13:14.915: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=packageName/.SelectType }
16:13:14.954: I/SurfaceFlinger(59): 
16:13:14.954: I/SurfaceFlinger(59): SurfaceFlinger::createSurface() : layer->mIdentity=176, LayerName= Starting packageName
16:13:14.954: I/SurfaceFlinger(59): SurfaceFlinger::createSurface() : layer->clientIndex=2, surfaceHandle->mToken=0x2
16:13:16.026: D/AnrParser(184): Waiting kernel log . . .
16:13:16.614: D/dalvikvm(6890): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 12274 objects / 785016 bytes in 135ms
16:13:17.784: D/dalvikvm(133): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 415 objects / 21624 bytes in 1285ms
16:13:17.914: D/dalvikvm(6890): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5762 objects / 339024 bytes in 90ms
16:13:18.174: D/AnrParser(184): Waiting kernel log . . .
16:13:18.344: E/keystore(6966): chdir: /data/misc/keystore: Permission denied
16:13:19.693: D/dalvikvm(6890): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 5994 objects / 372624 bytes in 93ms
16:13:20.173: D/AnrParser(184): Waiting kernel log . . .
16:13:22.173: D/AnrParser(184): Waiting kernel log . . .
16:13:22.743: I/SurfaceFlinger(59): 
16:13:22.743: I/SurfaceFlinger(59): SurfaceFlinger::createSurface() : layer->mIdentity=177, LayerName= packageName/packageName.SelectType
16:13:22.743: I/SurfaceFlinger(59): SurfaceFlinger::createSurface() : layer->clientIndex=0, surfaceHandle->mToken=0x0
16:13:22.983: D/dalvikvm(6890): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 21467 objects / 1097728 bytes in 119ms
16:13:23.403: E/keystore(6973): chdir: /data/misc/keystore: Permission denied
16:13:24.173: D/AnrParser(184): Waiting kernel log . . .
16:13:24.923: W/ActivityManager(59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
16:13:25.264: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{47f56388 packageName/.SelectType}
16:13:25.403: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity packageName/.SelectType: 10206 ms (total 10206 ms)
```

As you can see in above log, 1st statement is `16:13:14.915: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity` and last one is `16:13:25.403: I/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity`.

So there is a gap of approx. 10 to 11 seconds.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What are you doing in your `onCreate()`, `onResume()`, `onStart()` methods? If you do heavy work there, the app is bound to startup slowly.

Comment: even if I use just `setContentView(R.layout.main);`, then also it takes long time. I'm using `ViewFlipper` for my app which has approximately 50 screens within it.

Comment: please post your code for your launch activity

Comment: @GAMA : make sure u are not using big drawables for Views

Comment: I'm using drawables for each of the screen in form of header images, buttons, some other images,etc. Is it the reason for slow response?

Answer (score 2):

You might be executing something heavy on the onCreate() or onResume() of the activity...try to debug it to see if you are performing database or I/O operations in these methods directly. You can also activate the [StrictMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) for a better overview of what is slowing your app down.

Comment: even if I use just `setContentView(R.layout.main);`, then also it takes long time. I'm using `ViewFlipper` for my app which has approximately 50 screens within it.

Comment: LOL :) 50 screens in view flipper.

Comment: I have 6 to 7 different flows and each flow contain 7 to 8 screens. So it comes down to approx 50 screens

Comment: You should then consider using the ViewPager (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) where you can set an adapter preventing you from creating several views at one...50 screens in a view flipper is way too much.

Comment: Its available API 17 onward and is likely to change. So instead I would prefer some tested solution which is compatible with API 10 onward.

Comment: The ViewPager is in the support package available from API 4 onward.

Comment: Perform a right-click on the on your eclipse project then you choose Android Tools -> Add support library...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happens when I use the custom theme in the application tag and with app launcher Activity in Manifest File

Such that i use this custom theme

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppTheme"
```

But when I remove the theme from the application tag and change the app launcher Activity theme to the default theme my problem is Solve

I Change the app launcher Activity theme with

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```